# Problem with ovs-dpdk and Mellanox NIC

Tags: networking, drivers

I'm facing some problem with DPDK on Ubuntu 16.04 with a Mellanox 40G NIC.

I'm not able to assign the NIC to an ovs (trying to use vfio-pci driver).

When I try to assign the NIC to the OVS with the following command:

```
ovs-vsctl add-port br0 ens1 -- set Interface ens1 type=dpdk options:dpdk-devargs=0000:07:00.0
```

I get the following log message:

```
Apr 17 15:26:43 olnmalp026Bn001 ovs-vsctl: ovs|00001|vsctl|INFO|Called as ovs-vsctl add-port br0 ens1 -- set Interface ens1 type=dpdk options:dpdk-devargs=0000:07:00.0
Apr 17 15:26:43 olnmalp026Bn001 ovs-vswitchd[56850]: ovs|00184|dpdk|ERR|EAL: Driver cannot attach the device (0000:07:00.0)
Apr 17 15:26:43 olnmalp026Bn001 ovs-vswitchd[56850]: ovs|00185|dpdk|ERR|EAL: No port found for device (0000:07:00.0)
```

The strangest thing I've noticed, is that if I run dpdk-procinfo, I get the following output:

```
root@olnmalp026Bn001:/home/sysadmin# dpdk-procinfo
EAL: Detected 56 lcore(s)
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL:   cannot connect to primary process!
EAL: VFIO support could not be initialized
EAL: PCI device 0000:02:00.0 on NUMA socket 0
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1521 net_e1000_igb
EAL: PCI device 0000:02:00.1 on NUMA socket 0 
EAL:   probe driver: 8086:1521 net_e1000_igb
dpdk-procinfo [EAL options] -- -p PORTMASK
  -m to display DPDK memory zones, segments and TAILQ information
  -p PORTMASK: hexadecimal bitmask of ports to retrieve stats for
  --stats: to display port statistics, enabled by default
  --xstats: to display extended port statistics, disabled by default
  --metrics: to display derived metrics of the ports, disabled by default
  --xstats-name NAME: to display single xstat id by NAME
  --xstats-ids IDLIST: to display xstat values by id. The argument is comma-separated list of xstat ids to print out.
  --stats-reset: to reset port statistics
  --xstats-reset: to reset port extended statistics
  --collectd-format: to print statistics to STDOUT in expected by collectd format
  --host-id STRING: host id used to identify the system process is running on
EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
  Cause: No Ethernet ports - bye
```

**The Mellanox board, does not appear in the PCI devices listed in that command!**

```
root@olnmalp026Bn001:/home/sysadmin# lspci | grep -i mellan
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27710 Family [ConnectX-4 Lx]
```

But I am able to assign the PCI address to the vfio-pci driver:

```
root@olnmalp026Bn001:/home/sysadmin# dpdk-devbind -s

Network devices using DPDK-compatible driver
============================================
0000:07:00.0 'MT27710 Family [ConnectX-4 Lx] 1015' drv=vfio-pci unused=uio_pci_generic

Network devices using kernel driver
===================================
0000:02:00.0 'I350 Gigabit Network Connection 1521' if=enp2s0f0 drv=igb unused=vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic
0000:02:00.1 'I350 Gigabit Network Connection 1521' if=enp2s0f1 drv=igb unused=vfio-pci,uio_pci_generic
...
```

I think the Mellanox driver is properly installed in the machine:

```
root@olnmalp026Bn001:/home/sysadmin# mst start
Starting MST (Mellanox Software Tools) driver set
Loading MST PCI module - Success
[warn] mst_pciconf is already loaded, skipping
Create devices
Unloading MST PCI module (unused) - Success

root@olnmalp026Bn001:/home/sysadmin# lsmod | grep mst_
mst_pciconf           102400  0
```

Some data about the system, in case it helps:

```
root@olnmalp026Bn001:/home/sysadmin# uname -a
Linux olnmalp026Bn001 4.4.0-87-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 18 12:55:35 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@olnmalp026Bn001:/home/sysadmin# ovs-vsctl --version
ovs-vsctl (Open vSwitch) 2.9.0
DB Schema 7.15.1

root@olnmalp026Bn001:/home/sysadmin# dpkg -l | grep -i dpdk
ii  dpdk                                   17.11-5                                       amd64        Data Plane Development Kit (runtime)
ii  mlnx-ofed-dpdk                         4.3-1.0.1.0                                all          MLNX_OFED dpdk installer package (with DKMS support)
ii  openvswitch-switch-dpdk                2.9.0-2                                    amd64        DPDK enabled Open vSwitch switch implementation
```

Comment: Mellanox PMDs are only made available recently in the DPDK 17.11.x that is in Ubuntu 18.04 and later. Would you mind retrying with that and reporting an updated status then?

Comment: Actually I managed to make it work. The thing was that all the dpdk tutorials you can find out there are meant for intel NICs.
With Mellanox ones, the linux driver is 'smarter' and you have to skip some steps of the tutorials, but it's able to run over Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: What step did you skip? Can you please post a proper answer to your question if you've solved it, it can help others (me being the first)

Comment: You're totally right, I moved on this topic but checking my notes about it I had the following sentence:
There's a big difference betwee Mellanox and Intel NICs about DPDK. For Mellanox NICs, THERE'S NO NEED TO ASSIGN THE NIC TO DPDK DRIVER. The Mellanox driver is 'smart' and will handle DPDK itself.
So I guess I skipped the steps where you assign the nic card to the DPDK driver for intel cards.